# Git Diff: Does the index store a reference of what's in the head?

Tags: git

I am trying to wrap my head around using commands in bit like reset and checkout. I have been using a [visual aid](http://marklodato.github.io/visual-git-guide/index-en.html) but I am having trouble understanding some concepts. Namingly how the index really works.

For example, let's say I check out a repo that has a file in it named 'a.txt' with a bunch of text in it. If I make a few modifications, and then run `git diff` I see the changes between what the file was, and what it is now. I have learned that I am seeing the changes between my working tree and the index; this is where I get lost.

If `git diff` shows me the difference between my working tree and the index, wouldn't the whole file be additions since my index is empty? Or is there some sort of reference held to the HEAD when no entry for when a matching file isn't found inside the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your index is not empty; when you checkout a branch/commit, the index gets populated with the contents of that commit/branch. It is not so much a *reference* to HEAD as it is a *copy* of HEAD. That is why when you do a `git diff`, you don't see a bunch of additions; all those files are already in the index.

Answer (score 0):

The index is a list, indexed by pathname, of repository content that goes at interesting paths.  When you do a checkout, the index is loaded up with entries for each path checked out and the content that was checked out there.

When you `git add`, the content you're adding is put into the repository and the index entry for that path is updated to point to that. That's really all there is to it: it's just a list.  `git commit` writes a commit for the indexed content when you want.

So the default "git diff" is of whatever content was last checked out or added for a path against what's in your worktree.